# content-type in request header for sending json from angularjs to rest api

Tags: angularjs, restangular, request-headers

Im running a angular project on a server and trying to call the rest api running on another server
I have added the responce headers in filter on rest api as

```
responce.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
responce.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
responce.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
responce.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
```

In app.config I've added

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = {};
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.put = {};
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.patch = {};
```

Im using restangular to make http calls, the baseURL is set in app.config to the server in which restapi is running 
when the call sends a string it works fine but when I try to send a json Im getting an exception

```
        Restangular.all('userById').post(userName).then(function(result) {};        //working 
    //the rest receives the userName in a string 

    Restangular.all('saveUser').post(userInfo).then(function(result) {};        //not working
    //the rest receives the userInfo in a bean
```

Im getting this when Im sending an json

```
11:28:07,470 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher] (http-/0.0.0.0:8580-12) Failed executing POST service/saveUser: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.BadRequestException: Could not find message body reader for type: class com.org.User of content type: text/plain;charset="UTF-8"
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MessageBodyParameterInjector.inject(MessageBodyParameterInjector.java:153) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.injectArguments(MethodInjectorImpl.java:136) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:159) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:269) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:227) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:216) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:542) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:524) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:126) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at com.org.rest.impl.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:34) [classes:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
```

also when a json is passed the request headers is

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:88
Content-Type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8                   //has to be application/json
Host:172.16.177.65:8580
Origin:http://localhost:8180
Referer:http://localhost:8180/admin/indexHome.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36
```

so how do I change the content-type of request headers to json

Comment: It's a simple string, it doesn't make sense to set the header to `application/json`. And judging from the error message it wouldn't make things work. Your backend has to be able to create a new `User` instance based on a name, which doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: User here is a bean containing userName and userId and userInfo is a json having userName and userId

Comment: if I am to save a user how do I do it

Comment: I don't know your server side code, but I assume you have to send something like `{"userName": "new user"}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json` on your client.

Either globally if you're only using json :

```
RestangularProvider.setDefaultHeaders({Content-Type: "application/json"});
```

Or for each request.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can add this to your app.config

$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';